# Is there any way to CSS3 animation property like transform:rotatey(90deg) apply at every 5s with inifinite animation only with css3?

Tags: css, animation

I want this animation will happen after every 5sec.
Here is my code

css:

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 1s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: mymove 1s infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s; 
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    from {-webkit-transform:rotatey(0deg);}
    to {-webkit-transform:rotatey(180deg);}
}

@keyframes mymove {
    from {-webkit-transform:rotatey(0deg);}
    to {-webkit-transform:rotatey(180deg);}
}
```

HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 7s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: mymove 7s infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s; 
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
     0% {-webkit-transform:rotatey(0deg);}
    14.29% {-webkit-transform:rotatey(180deg);}
    28.57% {-webkit-transform:rotatey(0deg);} 
}

@keyframes mymove {
     0% {transform:rotatey(0deg);}
    14.29% {transform:rotatey(180deg);}
    28.57% {transform:rotatey(0deg);} 
}
```

Tested on Chrome and Firefox.

http://jsfiddle.net/58dex5oq/